# Js image slider with vertical align middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am in need of a js slider that allows me to display both landscape and portrait oriented images. The overflow of these images must be the same height on the top and bottom (ie. vertical-align: middle;). I've tried to do this with by adding code to my current slider with the name Nivo-slider but it does not work as good as I would like to.

Is there a slider that does this for me?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: My apologies MarsOne :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Cycle.js version2 that have vertical height feature,
check this:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/center.php